# Why to to use HTTP Headers to a websocket API?

Tags: javascript, http, https, websocket, http-headers

I am very new to this WebSocket and networking stuff. As someone suggested use HTTP header in WebSocket API. But I did not get answer why to use HTTP header? Is it good practice to go for it? 
Why it is beneficial?
I have some understanding of WebSocket as to stream data WebSocket is used, that's what our use case is. Please let me know why to usee http header in websocket api?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: is this relating to server or client side?

Comment: @JaromandaX if you can tell for both side then I can have broad knowlegde in this. Any article or any reference related to this will help me alot. I just wanted to start of things.

Comment: I'm asking you which side ... a browser will send HTTP headers when requesting a `ws://` resource, you have no control over them, a server needs to response with appropriate HTTP headers for the browser to continue with the connection of the websocket ... so, it's not a *suggestion* it's either totally out of your control (client) or necessary (server)